# transfer of the method from one component to another in the react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

is there a main component in which there is a gotoFirst method that returns to the beginning of the slider, how can this method be attached to a button from another component (in my case to the Opened component)? prescribed the , but as a result a working button appeared in this component, and the one that in Opened gives an error when clicked

Main.tsx;

```
class MainSliderComponent extends Component<any, any> {
  slider: any;
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      slideIndex: 0,
    };
  }
  goToFirst = () => {
    this.slider.slickGoTo(this.state.slideIndex);
  };
  render() {
    let settings = {
      infinite: false,
      centerMode: true,
      centerPadding: '60px',
      slidesToShow: 3,
      responsive: [
        {
          breakpoint: 768,
          settings: {
            arrows: false,
            centerMode: true,
            centerPadding: '40px',
            slidesToShow: 3,
          },
        },
        {
          breakpoint: 480,
          settings: {
            arrows: false,
            centerMode: true,
            centerPadding: '50px',
            slidesToShow: 1,
          },
        },
      ],
    };

    return (
      <div className="container">
        <Opened {...this.props} goToFirst={this.goToFirst} />
        <button onClick={this.goToFirst} value={this.state.slideIndex} />
        <Slider ref={(slider) => (this.slider = slider)} {...settings}>
          {RoomsService.rooms.map((room) => {
            return (
              <div className="rooms_slider">
                <Link to={`/rooms/${room.id}`}>
                  <img src={room.img} />
                </Link>
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </Slider>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Children.tsx;
class Opened extends Component<any, any> {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Opened">
        <button
          className="opened_button"
          onClick={() => {
            this.props.goToFirst();
          }}
        >
          Открыты
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: what is your question extacly?

Comment: @viciousP 
I have a button to which I need to bind the method from the parent, but in my code I have an identical button in the parent component (working), and in the child this button does not work

Comment: you said it gives an error, but you didn't put the error message in your question